# Can I use substr() to display on my website a value from column updated with getdate()?

Tags: php

Basically it works, but I am not sure if that's good to be used like that.
Let me explain. I've got a stored procedure (I'm using MSSQL Server 2005) which updates a column in my table with `GetDate()` and the result for example is like that: `2014-10-11 22:57:48.550` so when I display that column on my website it appears with the miliseconds, however I want to remove them. Can I use `substr()` to display only the first characters and in that way I can remove the last `.miliseconds` .. I tested it and it works but not sure if its good be used .. please let me know. That's my full function below where I use the `substr()` to display the time on my website.

```
   function ShowLLogins()
    {
        $db = $this->database[GGD];
        $num_rows = $db->doQuery('SELECT TOP 20 IPAddress, LTIME FROM Log WHERE UserName = ? ORDER BY LTIME DESC', $_SESSION['UserName']);

        if ($num_rows == -1)
        {
            return;
        }
        elseif ($num_rows == 0)
        {
            $this->content = Template::Load('llogins', array('show_llogins' => NULL, 'no_logins' => Template::GetLangVar('NO_LOGINS')));
            return;
        }

        $content = '';
        $flag = 1;
        while ($row = $db->doRead())
        {
            $content .= Template::Load('llogins-' . $flag++, 
                array
                (
                    'ip' => $row['IPAddress'],
                    'time' => substr($row['LTIME'], 0, 19)

// time returns value without the .miliseconds //
// example: 2014-10-11 22:57:48 instead 2014-10-11 22:57:48.550 //
                )
            );
            if ($flag > 2) $flag = 1;
        }

        $this->content = Template::Load('llogins', array('show_llogins' => $content, 'no_logins' => NULL));
    }
```

Comment: if it works , let it be as it is now!

Comment: Yeah, it does however I am not sure if that's good approach. That's what I mean.

Comment: if substr works, go for it. its low weight compared to parsing into a date and then reformatting the output.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will got for it in that case. It's appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you consider using [DATE_FORMAT](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp) in the MySQL

```
SELECT TOP 20 IPAddress, DATE_FORMAT(LTIME,'%Y-%M-%D %T') AS LTIME FROM Log WHERE UserName = ? ORDER BY LTIME DESC
```

Comment: I am using MSSQL Server 2005 as stated on my main post and this won't help me out. Still thanks for suggestion.

Comment: How about this [Site](http://anubhavg.wordpress.com/2009/06/11/how-to-format-datetime-date-in-sql-server-2005/) will this helps?

Answer (score 0):

I would not call cutting the time string using `substr()` good practice. You can, and probably should do it on the database side. In T-SQL it would be something like this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar, LTIME, 101)
```

Using the code `101` like above will format your date like `mm/dd/yyyy`.

[Here's a list of other formats.](http://anubhavg.wordpress.com/2009/06/11/how-to-format-datetime-date-in-sql-server-2005/)

Comment: I understand, however, I can only do it in the php script when it's displaying. It's not good practice but it's not incorrect, right?

Comment: @Monk25 It obviously works but wouldn't you rather use the PHP date functions to format your datetime? What I'm talking about is not whether it works or it doesn't, rather whether it's understandable and logical code. It would be clearer to a programmer that you wanted to reformat the date if you used the date functions rather than string functions. But maybe I'm too picky sometimes.

Comment: You totally correct but my string is like that in the table: `2014-10-11 22:57:48.550` so somehow I should format the string in the array where it will be displayed without the `.miliseconds`. The convert won't work for some reason on my script when it's selecting LTIME to display it ..

Comment: @Monk25 What is the type of the column `LTIME` ?

Comment: @Monk25 If it's a datetime then it should work, if it's a string then you can cast it like this: `SELECT convert(varchar, CAST(LTIME as datetime), 101)`.